# "Signing key does not exist" after successful upload on Launchpad

Tags: application-development, ppa, repository, launchpad, add-apt-repository

I have added my package as a ppa successfully (it says `Successfully uploaded packages` with the command `dput ppa:user/my_package my_package_0.3-1_source.changes`).

However, It says that the signing key does not exist when I add my ppa with add-apt`and after pressing`[ ENTER ]`:

```
  # add-apt-repository ppa:my_user/my_package
  More info: https://launchpad.net/~user3514/+archive/ubuntu/screen-generator
  Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

   Error: signing key fingerprint does not exist
```

Output after uploading the package:

```
# dput ppa:user/my_package source.changes
Checking signature on .changes
gpg: Signature made Tue 11 Oct 2016 12:10:31 PM CEST using RSA key ID 1BDEE64F
gpg: Good signature from "Firstname Name <mymail@gmail.com>"
Good signature on /media/git/my_package_0.3-1_source.changes.
Checking signature on .dsc
gpg: Signature made Tue 11 Oct 2016 12:10:20 PM CEST using RSA key ID 1BDEE64F
gpg: Good signature from "Firstname Name <mymail@gmail.com>"
Good signature on /media/git/my_package_0.3-1.dsc.
Uploading to ppa (via ftp to ppa.launchpad.net):
Uploading my_package_0.3-1.dsc: done.
Uploading my_package_0.3-1.tar.gz: done.    
Uploading my_package_0.3-1_source.changes: done.
Successfully uploaded packages.
```

Comment: Probably the key did not reach all servers.

Answer (score 5):

PPA will create a new key(**Launchpad PPA for YOUR NAME**) for you and signed the related files with this new key.

You may need to wait for a while, to get this new key uploaded to Ubuntu Keyserver(keyserver.ubuntu.com).

Comment: How long is a while, and after waiting a while, what steps do I take?